# Sonarqube: How to get rid of duplicate issues?

Tags: sonarqube

**Situation**

I am running Sonarqube 5.2.  Due to changes with how we run Sonarqube via CI, I needed to update my project keys.  This is a Maven-based Java project (i.e., submodules).  The key changed was to simply add the branch to the key for the parent and all sub-modules.  After updating all the keys I ran the new CI job.

**Problem**

After doing so our unresolved issue count went from 223 to 883.  Strangely enough, the projects dashboard still displays 223.  However, if click that 223 issue count link to drill into them the number jumps to 883.

If I use the default "My Issues" filter it says I have 74.  If I try to navigate/view each one of them I can't get past 11/74 (I click but the paging control just flashes yellow).

**What doesn't work**

Since I can't delete these mysteriously inaccessible issues I thought I'd mark them all as "Won't Fix".  However, attempting this has no impact on the "Unresolved" issues/count.  Viewing sonar.log the POST to make the change returns a 200.

**Question**

Is there anything I am missing within the web application that can address this.  Or is there any SQL I can run?

**FWIW**

I subsequently did the same process for a Javascript project with any issue duplication

Comment: To clarify: you updated they keys both in your project(s) and in the SonarQube server?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, the key updates were all fine.  The problem was the Elasticsearch index.  I've detailed things in my answer below.  Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In trying to revert things I figured this one out.

The very first time we ran the CI changes we had failed to update the project keys first.  In all the attempts to fix via restores/retries all we did was reimport the database backup.  The culprit was the Elasticsearch cache.  The duplicates only existed in the context of the ES index due to the initial failure to update the keys first.

In the end, I ended up deleting the `<sonar>/data/es`, restoring the database, updating the project keys, and the running the analysis via CI.